# I've finally gotten it working!

Tags: present-perfect, causative-get

Would an American speaker say the following in a context where they've just fixed some mechanical issue in a machine?

"There, I've finally **gotten** it working!"

Comment: I’m sure there is some American among the 330 million of us that might say that.

Comment: Thank you! So in "I got it working", "got" is the past form of "get". Am I right?

Comment: What else do you think “got” could be?

Comment: Actually sometimes people use just "got" to mean "have got", as in "I got your back". This "got" is not the past of "get".

Comment: I know one US citizen who would say 'Enfin, je l'ai fait marcher !'

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to clarify why you are asking. Currently, it seems like you want a "yes" or "no" opinion instead of a proper answer that might help clear up some confusion about the usage of "have gotten".